# Is there any direct way to create rdf file like sitemap .xml file

Tags: xml, rdf

I want to create rdf file like sitemap.xml file.How is it possible?

Comment: Start your favorite text editor, and start typing. (Or, give some details on your environment, so someone can give better answers than my smartass comment. :)

Comment: i am very new to this field so any comments are welcome.

Comment: As far as I am aware, sitemap.xml isn't an rdf file; so I'm not sure what you are asking for.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use the straight sitemap.xml and use XSLT+GRDDL to define a conversion to RDF. This allows you to transparently support legacy systems, but also to use rdf internally for any site analysis you want to perform.